# Swipe to expose “More” "Flag" "Archive" buttons (like in Mail app on iOS 8)

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

How to expose custom buttons when user swipe a cell in table view (like mail app in iOS 8)

I would like that when the user swiping on a table view cell, to expose buttons (The default is the delete button in iOS 7 and early). 
In the Mail app for iOS 8 you can swipe and expose 3 buttons “More” "Flag" "Archive".
I want to display other buttons with different color and title.

Is Apple provides API in UITableView for this ?

Thanks